# sometimes, vpn connection doesn't work on ipsec(strongswan) configuration

Tags: vpn, ipsec, site-to-site-vpn, strongswan

I'm using ipsec with strongswan between aws and on-premise
here is strongswan configuration

```
config setup
    uniqueids = no
    charondebug="ike 1, knl 1, cfg 0"

conn %default
  ikelifetime=14400
  keylife=3600
  keyexchange=ikev2
  dpdaction=clear
  rekey=no
  dpddelay = 300s
  dpdtimeout = 30

conn AWS-VPN-1
  authby=secret
  auto=start
  type=tunnel
  leftauth=psk
  rightauth=psk
  left = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   # On-Premise IP Address
  right = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # AWS VPN Tunnel 1 IP Address
  leftsubnet = 172.17.200.200/32  # On-Premise CIDR
  rightsubnet = 10.0.0.0/8 # AWS VPC CIDR
  ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
  esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048

conn AWS-VPN-2
  authby=secret
  auto=start
  type=tunnel
  leftauth=psk
  rightauth=psk
  left = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx   # On-Premise IP Address
  right = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx  # AWS VPN Tunnel 1 IP Address
  leftsubnet = 172.17.200.200/32  # On-Premise CIDR
  rightsubnet = 10.0.0.0/8 # AWS VPC CIDR
  ike=aes256-sha256-modp2048
  esp=aes256-sha256-modp2048
```

After connection is initialized, vpn connection is working good.
-> "A" Server on rightsubnet can connect to "B" server on leftsubnet.

But, as times pass , vpn connection doesn't work.
-> "A" Server on rightsubnet **can not  connect** to "B" server on leftsubnet

Comment: `as times pass` Minutes? Hours? Days? Amount? What does a packet capture show?